# Как передать тип в качестве аргумента golang

Tags: golang, gorm, fiber

Я хочу хочу передать в функцию тип, и создать элемент этого класса.
Примерно так (мне это нужно для gorm)

```
func function(type interface{}, ctx *fiber.Ctx) {
    model := type{}
    _ := ctx.BodyParser(&model)
    gorm.DB.Create(&model)
}
```

Возможно ли это?

Comment: очень похоже на дженерики:)

Comment: Пока что никак. Типизированные параметры собираются добавить следующую версию языка Go. Но если подумать, зачем вам типовой параметр? Вы и так знаете тип - создайте объект заранее и передайте его функцию. Функция его за вас заполнит. Так, например, устроен парсер для JSON.